# Finding character index from a string variable (TSQL)

Tags: t-sql

I was trying the following but i don't know why i am getting different results.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME') -- returns 10 (expected output)

DECLARE @FULLNAME VARCHAR = 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME'
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @FULLNAME) -- returns 0
```

Comment: What database engine is this? Does `DECLARE @FULLNAME VARCHAR = 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME'` actually work?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server, yes it works. You can do declaration and assignment in one line. The issue was with not explicitly specifying the value of n for VARCHAR -- answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify `VARCHAR` TO `VARCHAR(50)`.

FROM [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME' is truncated to 'F', that's why you got 0.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't valid

```
DECLARE @FULLNAME VARCHAR = 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME'
```

try

```
DECLARE @FULLNAME VARCHAR
SET @FULLNAME = 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME'
```

Comment: DECLARE @FULLNAME VARCHAR = 'FIRSTNAME LASTNAME' works fine, declaration and assignment can be done all in one line.

Comment: Been doing this too long, your correct you can since SQL 2008.